# New to REST API and Express not understanding repeat results

Tags: api, rest, express

When I run my code the first time I get the correct output, but if I refresh that page and run the code again the output contains the first output plus the new output.  To get a fresh form I have to restart the server and refresh the page, can anyone explain why this happens and how I can get around it.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');
var PORT = 3000;

var x = {
"word" : null,
"maxValue" : null
}

var maxValueArray = [];
var output = {
        "status": "ok",
        "results": []
    }

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/'));

//GET
app.get('/', function (req,res) {
    res.send();
}); 

app.post('/', function(req, res) {

var word = req.body.word;
var maxValue = req.body.maxValue;

if (word != "fizz" && word != "buzz" && word != "fizzbuzz") {
        output.status = "error";
    return res.status(400).send(output);
}

if (maxValue < 1) {
    output.status = "error";
    return res.status(400).send(error); 
}

var html;
for (i=1; i <= maxValue; i++) {
    maxValueArray.push(i);
    }                   

    if (word === "fizz" && maxValue > 0) {
    maxValueArray.forEach(function (index){
        if (index%3 === 0) {
            output.results.push(index); 
            return html = output;                                       
        }       
    });

    res.send(html);
    } else if (word === "buzz" && maxValue > 0) {

        maxValueArray.forEach(function (index){
            if (index%5 === 0) {
                output.results.push(index); 
                html = output;                                      
            }
        }); return res.send(html);

    } else if (word === 'fizzbuzz' && maxValue > 0) {
        maxValueArray.forEach(function (index){
            if (index%3 === 0 && index%5 === 0) {
                output.results.push(index); 
                html = output;                          
            }
        }); return res.send(html);  
} 
});
app.listen(PORT, function () {
console.log('Express listening on port ' + PORT);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should declare the variables maxValueArray and output inside the callback function.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');
var PORT = 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/'));

//GET
app.get('/', function (req,res) {
        res.send();
}); 

app.post('/', function(req, res) {

        var x = {
            "word" : null,
            "maxValue" : null
        }

        var maxValueArray = [];
        var output = {
            "status": "ok",
            "results": []
        }

        var word = req.body.word;
        var maxValue = req.body.maxValue;

        if (word != "fizz" && word != "buzz" && word != "fizzbuzz") {
            output.status = "error";
            return res.status(400).send(output);
        }

        if (maxValue < 1) {
            output.status = "error";
            return res.status(400).send(error); 
        }

        var html;
        for (i=1; i <= maxValue; i++) {
            maxValueArray.push(i);
        }                   

        if (word === "fizz" && maxValue > 0) {
            maxValueArray.forEach(function (index){
                    if (index%3 === 0) {
                        output.results.push(index); 
                        return html = output;                                       
                    }       
            });

            res.send(html);
        } else if (word === "buzz" && maxValue > 0) {

            maxValueArray.forEach(function (index){
                    if (index%5 === 0) {
                        output.results.push(index); 
                        html = output;                                      
                    }
            }); return res.send(html);

        } else if (word === 'fizzbuzz' && maxValue > 0) {
            maxValueArray.forEach(function (index){
                    if (index%3 === 0 && index%5 === 0) {
                        output.results.push(index); 
                        html = output;                          
                    }
            }); return res.send(html);  
        } 
});
app.listen(PORT, function () {
        console.log('Express listening on port ' + PORT);
});
```

Comment: That worked - thanks!  Can you explain why it worked.